# Pandas : Getting indexes of a series providing multiple filters

Tags: python, pandas

I am iterating over a dataframe. In each iteration, I need to get indexes of the series where the value is equal 5 or 4. Following code gives me the indexes where the value is 5 ( another problem: actually i am getting both index and the value. Another problem is getting only the index. I tried `print row[row ==5].index[0]` but it does not do the job for me)

```
def get_top_rated_movies(user_ratings):
for index, row in user_ratings.iterrows():
    print row[row == 5]
```

I think I have to do `row[row == 5 || row == 4]` kind of a thing but have no idea.

here 'user_ratings' is a dataframe. Each row is a user and column is a movie where I store users ratings for movies. I need to get the movies which got 4 or 5 ratings for each user. So, I iterate over the dataframe and above code gives me (both movie id and rating)

```
movie_id
1      5
9      5
13     5
15     5
16     5
19     5
32     5
42     5
45     5
48     5
50     5
55     5
57     5
59     5
87     5
```

Comment: Can you add some data and desired output?

Comment: So second or last solution works?

Comment: Thanks. user_ratings[(user_ratings == 5) | (user_ratings == 4)] works for me where user_ratings is a series. But I am getting both index and rating as the result.  See my output in my question. How can I get the only index?

Comment: use `user_ratings.index[(user_ratings == 5) | (user_ratings == 4)]`

Comment: Yes it is  working

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you can use [`boolean indexing`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/indexing.html#boolean-indexing):

If `user_ratings` is `Series`:

```
user_ratings[(user_ratings == 5) | (user_ratings == 4)]
```

Or better:

```
user_ratings[user_ratings.isin([4,5])]
```

And if need indexes filter:

```
user_ratings.index[(user_ratings == 5) | (user_ratings == 4)]
user_ratings.index[user_ratings.isin([4,5])]
```

Or first filter `Series` and then get indexes:

```
user_ratings[(user_ratings == 5) | (user_ratings == 4)].index
user_ratings[user_ratings.isin([4,5])].index
```